# Implementing Matlab mrdivide using QR Decomposition and Solving in C

Tags: c, matlab, math, microcontroller, mathematical-optimization

I've used `x=B/A` ([mrdivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)) in Matlab to find x in equation `xA=B`. I am trying to achieve this without Matlab environment using a C based fixed point library for microcontrollers called [libfixmatrix](https://github.com/PetteriAimonen/libfixmatrix).

How would I proceed with using [QR Decomposition](https://github.com/PetteriAimonen/libfixmatrix/blob/master/FUNCTIONS.rst#mf16-qr-decomposition) and [Solve](https://github.com/PetteriAimonen/libfixmatrix/blob/master/FUNCTIONS.rst#mf16-solve) function's of libfixmatrix to solve `xA=B`?

QR Decomposition and Solving is equivalent to solving for `Ax=B`. But I have a scenario where x is in equation `xA=B`

It was mentioned in the readme of the repository that :

> Libfixmatrix is suited well for tasks involving small matrices (often
>   less than 10x10)

Is it efficient to use libfixmatrix for say 80*80 ?

Answer (score 0):

just a silly suggestion:

```
x.A = B
x.A.inverse(A) = B.inverse(A)
x = B.inverse(A)
```

So you just need to compute **Inverse matrix** and **matrix multiplication** which are basic operations. Use Sub-determinant approach. Also if `A,B` are not square matrices resize them so they are.